TemplateNotFound jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
I'm working on a Flask application, but I'm encountering a TemplateNotFound error for index.html even though I believe my file structure is correct. Below are the details of my setup:
project_root/
│
├── app.py
├── requirements.txt
│
├── static/
│   ├── style.css
│   └── script.js
│
├── templates/
│   ├── index.html
│   └── recommendations.html
│
├── ai/
│   ├── gemini_api.py
│   ├── google_cloud_vision.py
│   └── recommendation.py
│
├── database/
│   ├── models.py
│   └── database.py
│
└── utils/
    ├── authentication.py
    └── helpers.py

What I Tried:

Double-Checked File Paths:

I verified that the index.html file is located in the templates directory, which is at the same level as app.py.

I ensured that the app.py file uses the correct path to the template with render_template('index.html').



Verified File Permissions:

I checked the file permissions to make sure that index.html is readable by the Flask application.


Confirmed Directory Structure:

I made sure that the directory structure of my project matches the expected layout for Flask projects, with templates and static directories at the same level as app.py.


Tested Flask's Static File Serving:

I verified that static files (CSS and JS) are correctly served by accessing them directly in the browser. This ensures that Flask's file serving mechanism is working as expected.


Examined Flask Configuration:

I ensured that there are no custom configurations in my Flask app that might change the default behavior of template and static file locations.



What I Was Expecting:

I expected the render_template('index.html') call in my Flask route to find and render the index.html file located in the templates directory without raising a TemplateNotFound error.

When navigating to the root URL (/), the browser should display the content of index.html.


Despite these efforts, I am still encountering the jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html error. Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

"I ensured that there are no custom configurations in my Flask app that might change the default behavior of template and static file locations." - Instead of explaining what your code does and what your code does not, just add your code into the question post (in form of [mcve]).
